Why is version showing as "42" instead of "6.6.1" in dashboard
Why do you think this is happening? I just updated a bunch of client sites and they all show me running 6.6.1, but this particular site says simply "42" for the version. I've reinstalled the core files using wp-cli (core verifies against checksums) and updated everything and this persists.



The answer should be encoded in that number  If you are not successful decoding that number try deactivate plugins one by one, look into must-use plugins or theme finctions.php. Looks like some hosts might offer this version filtering https://managingwp.io/2022/05/24/gridpane-caveats/#3_security

you are right! I use Gridpane. Thanks!

The answer is What do you get when you multiply six by nine?

This turns out to be Gridpane, as suggested by @birgire, using an option called "Block wp-version".

This appears to be a little easter egg/nod to the hitchhikers guide to the galaxy https://news.mit.edu/2019/answer-life-universe-and-everything-sum-three-cubes-mathematics-0910#:~:text=The%20number%2042%20is%20especially,know%20the%20answer%20to%2042.
Hiding the Wordpress version is known as security by obscurity in an attempt to divert hackers exploiting known vulnerabilities in certain versions of Wordpress.
